# HTTPS Авторизация HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Здравствуйте, перейду сразу к делу.
Пытаюсь освоить httpwebrequest, Хочу парсить кое какие значения с сайта на который нужно вначале авторизироваться через https, и не могу понять что я упускаю, потому-что каждый раз получаю ответ что логин и пароль не верны. подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://login.bookatable.com/Common/Logon");
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;


        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "userEmail=my@email.com&password=MyP@$$worD&selectedCulture=en-GB";

            sw.Write(json);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            textBox1.Text = result;
        }
```

когда шлю запрос на /Common/Logon получаю ошибку сервера E-20180130-218A4EF5F8
когда шлю запрос на /login говорит что пароль или майл не верные [image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на то, что принимает сервер если зайти через сайт. У вас идет отправка на "/Common/Logon" данные не в `JSON`, а обычная форма, то есть `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. Еще замечу, что ваши данные, которые вы пытаетесь сейчас отправить - это не `JSON`, а обычный набор данных. `JSON` должен выглядеть примерно так `{"param" : "value", "param2" : true}`.

Comment: спасибо всё получилось

Comment: Давайте тогда закроем вопрос. Составил ответ, поставьте "галку" сбоку, если он вам помог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим что должен получить сервер:

- Для этого откроем программу для отлавливания всех запросов (в вашем случае это Fiddler).
- Настроим ее для отслеживания запросов.
- Зайдем на нужный сайт и сделаем стандартную авторизацию с помощью формы.
- В нашей программе должны получить сам запрос со всеми его "внутренностями".

Хорошо, смотрим что мы отправляем: Мы отправляем `POST` запросом `Cookie`, тело запроса формата `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` и в кодировке `UTF-8`, ну а также всякие параметры по типу `Referer` и др. Зачастую для успешного ответа нам достаточно составить грамотно "тело" запроса, в некоторых случаях требуются еще `Cookie`, а в некоторых и вовсе все параметры должны быть идентичны. В вашем случае я думаю просто надо грамотно отправить  тело на нужный адрес.

Для отправки я лично люблю использовать `HttpClient`. Покажу на его примере что нам нужно:

```
public async Task<string> SendRequest(CancellationToken ct)
{
    string data;
    var baseAddress = new Uri("https://..."); //Базовый адрес 
    var url = "/login"; //Нужная нам страница, на которую пойдет запрос
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); //Показываю как отправлять Cookie (для примера, если необходимо). Можно убрать.

    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36 OPR/49.0.2725.64"); //Добавляем нужные нам параметры в запрос (на примере UserAgent'a)
        cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("lang", "en")); //Добавляем необходимые Cookie

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", "xxxxx"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pass", "yyyyy")
        }); //Наше тело, которое при помощи FormUrlEncodedContent закодируется в нужное нам "тело".

        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content, ct); //Отправляем на нужную страницу POST запрос с нашем телом, также тут используется CancellationToken для грамотной отмены async методов.
        var bytes = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); 
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        data = encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Все эти три строки добавлены тут для того, что бы получать данные в нужной нам кодировке (некоторые сервера к примеру выдают в неверной кодировке и может выдать ошибку). Вообще можно все 3 строки заменить на одну:
        //data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); Тогда кодировка будет той, что выдает сервер.
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

    return data;
}
```

Вроде везде где надо оставил комментарии, трудностей не возникнет.

В общем, подытожим: Судя по тому, что Вы предоставили, и тому, что я увидел при просмотре страницы логина вывод прост, ваш запрос отправляет неверный формат, а именно `application/json`, когда сам сервер ждет от вас `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Также, если скажем сервер принимал бы `JSON` тело, вы сам `JSON` неверно пишете, формат должен быть `{"param" : "value", "param2" : true}` или ему подобный.