# WebClient ошибка кодировки текста

Tags: c#, webclient

```
  private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://site.com")
           
        };

        public async Task<string> testAsync()
        {
              Dictionary<string, string> formData = new Dictionary<string, string>
             {
             
            {"id", ""},
            {"Msg", "тест тест"},
             }
        };

            string contents = await PostForm1251Async("index.php", formData);
             return contents;
              
        }
 
        private static async Task<string> PostForm1251Async(string path, Dictionary<string, string> formData)
        {
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
            string formEncoded = string.Join("&", formData.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x.Value, encoding)}"));
            using (HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(encoding.GetBytes(formEncoded)))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(path, content))
                {
                    return await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Отправляю запрос к сайту, на сайте публикуется значение из `values["Msg"]`
Но вместо `тест, тест, тест` выходит `Рўрµсђсњрµр·рѕрѕрўрµсђсњрµр·рѕрѕрўрµсђсњрµр·рѕрѕ`

Как изменить кодировку?
Спасибо

Comment: Перестаньте использовать `WebClient` (почему - читайте документацию)

Comment: Никогда не используйте `Encoding.Default` - это кодировка по умолчанию на данном компьютере. На другом компьютере (сервере) она может быть другая.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Переделал под WebRequest, проблема с кодировкой осталась

Comment: Вы [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient) явно не читали... `WebClient Класс использует WebRequest класс для предоставления доступа к ресурсам.` и далее `Мы не рекомендуем использовать WebClient класс для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте System.Net.Http.HttpClient класс.`. В C# все, что базируется на `WebRequest` давно устарели, на их смену рекомендуется использовать `HttpClient`. Также, не используйте кодирование, зачем оно вам тут?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, переделал под HttpClient, проблема с кодировкой осталась (обновил код в первом сообщении)

Comment: А я вам и не говорил, что это решит проблему, я вам лишь сказал, что в C# использовать что-то, кроме `HttpClient` сейчас это не хорошо. Касательно проблемы, если вы отправляете данные на сервер и там они в неверной кодировке, то эта проблема сервера (ИМХО), ибо он нарушил стандарт. Если же вы в `var contents` получаете белебирду, тогда да, тут надо чуть подправить кодировку (я это делал к примеру [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777512/220553)).

Comment: Все заработало, большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: А как заработало, вы нам не скажете. Тогда в чем польза вашего вопроса для SO, который является не форумом, а базой "вопрос-ответ"? На данный момент это просто мусор, который захламляет эту базу. Если хотите исправить, то давайте ответ сами. Думайте пожалуйста не только о себе, но и о сообществе!